# PHP make object available globally for ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, object

I believe this may be a duplication of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547750/php-jquery-and-ajax-object-orientation) but I don't really understand the answer

I would like to create a new object at the start of my script/page.  The page has multiple steps and I would like to use Ajax with separate PHP files for each step.  A couple of these steps though would require making amendments to the object.

What is the correct approach to do this.  I am using JQuery Ajax.

It is basically a checkout page but the latter stages are generated depending on the options selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is keep that data accessible over multiple connections - persisting the data. It's really simple in PHP, just use sessions.

First of all, if you want to access the persistent data (or store any) you'll need to start a session. Do that like so:

```
session_start();
```

From then on, anything you add into that will be stored (with some exceptions - for example, storing a MySQL connection probably won't work too well). Don't worry though - the data only persists for the user. Other people won't be able to access other people's shopping carts or progress in the form, for example.

Here's how you store data against the session:

```
$obj = new MrClass();
$_SESSION['form_object'] = $obj;
```

Later on, just access it as you always would:

```
$_SESSION['form_object']->someMethod();
```

Remeber though: each AJAX request must begin with `session_start()`.

Comment: I never said you have to explicitly serialize it, but when you stick it into session, that is what is happening. And if you have, say, a PDO connection as a class member, then trying to implicitly serialize it (ie $_SESSION['x'] = $ojb) won't work. You'll have to nullify the connection, or override __sleep (http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you need data to persist across multiple requests, you should use sessions or cookies.

Comment: So from the original question I linked to this is done as $_SESSION['my_object'] = serialize($my_object);

Comment: @MattP: You don't need to use serialize, see my answer for an example.

Comment: Using serialize will shrink down the size of the object that your sticking into the session.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the object representative of a database table. If it is a User object, create your user table, and modify the object by loading it with an ID via the JSON request. Essentially, un freeze it whenever you make an AJAX request, then modify it, and stick it back in the database.

Or, you could just stick it into `$_SESSION`, but keep in mind your object must be able to serialize itself fully.